# Computing the linking number of a link without a diagram

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm working on a question in which two explicit knots $K_0,K_1 \subseteq S^3$ are given and the task is to compute the (unsigned) linking number of $L = K_0 \cup K_1$. I'm not really sure how to approach this. I know there's an integral involving the Gauss map that, in theory, can yield the desired number, and there's also a homological approach that I don't really understand.

> **Question.** In general terms, how might one approach a problem such as this?

**Addendum.** The specific link I'm dealing with is: $$K_0 = \{(e^{i\theta}/\sqrt{2},e^{n i \theta}/\sqrt{2}):\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}, \qquad K_1 = \{(0,e^{i\theta}) : \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

I'm not looking for an answer, but I just wanted a hand getting started. If I'm not mistaken, the linking number should be $n$. To show this, I was thinking of trying to "non-injectively" deform $K_0$ into $$K_0'\{(e^{i\theta},0):\theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ in such a way that it ends up looping around $K_0'$ $n$-times. I don't know if this is really the right approach, and if it is I don't know how to get started doing it. In any event, some general advice on how to approach questions of this form would be helpful for me and possibly for others.

Comment: Just check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Computing_the_linking_number

Comment: @CamiloArosemena-Serrato, I'm not sure I understand your comment. $K_0$ and $K_1$ are explicitly given by formulae and set-builder notation. Are you suggesting that one can use the formulae to obtain such a diagram?

Comment: The linking number is the degree of the Gauss map - you need not take the homological approach - you can also define the degree of a map via differential topology. In practice, computing the linking number as a double integral or as the degree of the Gauss map is quite difficult in all but simple cases.